# endophyte studies OR the studies of endophytes?

Tags: research, terminology, biology

Which is better to describe research into microorganism, especially fungi: *endophyte studies* or *the study of endophytes*?

Comment: I respectfully disagree with Kimball about closing the question. What to call new things, whether newly opened areas of inquiry, or new inventions would reasonably seem to be a valuable function of this site.

Comment: No need for an article; _studies of endophytes_ is perfectly standard.

Comment: @brasshat My comment got migrated from the original post on Academia.SE, so I wasn't talking about this site.

Answer (score 1):

Endophytes are a class of fungi and bacteria that live part of their life in a plant, without causing disease or injury to the plant. At one time, I expect the field of inquiry which studied endophytes would likely have been named *endophytology*, but it would not surprise me in modern academia if the field of inquiry was named *Endophyte studies".

It's not going to matter either way. Neither is particularly wrong, but neither is particularly elegant, either. As a title or department in an institution, I would likely prefer *Endophyte studies*; in the title of a class, I favor *Endophytology*, and in most other instances I would lean towards *the study of endophytes*.